# how to merge field from mongodb collection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

that's my model

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    title:  String,
    link: String,
    gid: Number,
    posts: [],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, 
}, { collection: 'Group' });

var Group = mongoose.model('Group', schema);
```

I need to get all posts objects from collection by one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mongoose it should work with the following statement using a projection to return only the posts field (and the `_id` field)

```
Group.find({},{"posts":1} ).exec(callback)
```

To only get all posts you have to use an aggregation.

```
Group.aggregate([{$unwind : "$posts"}, {$project: {"post":"$posts", _id:0}}]).exec(callback)
```

Comment: thats return parent objects from db that content posts, but i need to merge all posts into one global object posts.